# Required: Double, int Found: String, String

Tags: java, string, int, double

Here is my code:-

public class Program {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args[0] == "interest"){
        public CompoundInerestCalculator(){
            CompoundInterestCalculator runCal = new CompoundInterestCalculator();
            if (args[1] == "annual"){
                runCal.compoundAnnually(args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]);

            }

            else {
                args[1] = "continuous";
                runCal.continuousCompound(args[2], args[3], args[4]);
            }
        }   
    }
```

The next class from where it is pulling the code:-

public class CompoundInterestCalculator {

```
// Calculation for Annual Compound Interest
public BigDecimal compoundAnnually(double principal, double rate, int periods, int years) {
    double finalAmount = principal * Math.pow( 1 + ( rate / periods), years * periods);
    double compoundInterest = finalAmount - principal;
    BigDecimal finalInterest = new BigDecimal(compoundInterest);
    System.out.print(finalInterest);
        return finalInterest;
}

// Calculation for Continuous Compound Interest
public BigDecimal continuousCompound(double principal, double rate, int years) {
    double finalAmount = principal * Math.pow( Math.E, rate * years);
    double compoundInterest = finalAmount - principal;
    BigDecimal finalInterest = new BigDecimal(compoundInterest);
    System.out.print(finalInterest);
        return finalInterest;
}
```

}

Here is thee problem when I compile the Program:-

required: double,double,int,int

found: String,String,String,String

reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to double by method invocation conversion

Program.java:19: error: method continuousCompound in class CompoundInterestCalculator cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: Java is strongly typed. You have to convert these strings into relevant types explicitly.

Comment: @lared So you mean to say, I gotta explicitly type args[no.] as the types needed, after the line runCal.compoundAnnually(args, args)?

Comment: You have to use methods like Jean-Francois mentioned in his answer - Double.parseDouble

Comment: @lared Okay, got that :)

Answer (score 0):

First, compare String with `.equals` not `==` as you are comparing the memory address when using `==` to compare objects.

So `(args[0] == "interest")` become `(args[0].equals("interest"))`

Second, you are passing `String`s to a method declared as

```
compoundAnnually(double principal, double rate, int periods, int years)
```

With this call

```
runCal.compoundAnnually(args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]);
```

You need to parse them to the correct type...

```
runCal.compoundAnnually(Double.parseDouble(args[2]), Double.parseDouble(args[3]), Integer.parseInt(args[4]), Integer.parseInt(args[5]))
```

Third, apply the same for the call `runCal.continuousCompound(args[2], args[3], args[4]);`

Comment: Well the error did go away, but some other errors popped up :D
Thanks for the help :)